# Can't lock the top of image in the top of the screen while scrolling the page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiwebviewdelegate

I a uiimage that I use as cover photo, and I want to use the scroll view to pull down and enlarge but I want the top of the image to stay on top:

[image]

and this is the method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;{

    CGFloat offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    offset = offset + 54;


    if (offset < 0 && offset > -25) {
        _coverImageView.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 0,320 + (-offset) * 2, 150 + (-offset));
    }

    NSLog(@"%f", offset);
}
```

tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use imageview behind the scrolview with clear background and resize while scrolling according to offset.

```
  OR
```

This may help
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/secret-viewer